# LNK2019 can't link static library in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

*I read a lot of LNK2019 related questions. But I am still confused with my situation. I apologize if I missed something obvious.*

I tried to use wolfssl library. It is C library. Here is my c++ code that I tried to build in VS 2017:

```
extern "C" {
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/sha3.h>


int main() {
    Sha3  sha3;
    wc_InitSha3_256(&sha3, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
}
```

I got
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _wc_InitSha3_256

I performed next steps:

1. I rebuilt wolfssl from source.
2. I made sure that lib contain _wc_InitSha3_256
3. I added full path to lib file in Properties->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies (no spaces in path)
4. I wrapped up my code with extern "C"
5. I tried run VS with administrator privileges

Still have same error. Any ideas?

Update:
To have `_wc_InitSha3_256()` define symbol `WOLFSSL_SHA3` required

My link configuration:
[image: My link configuration]

Comment: Which library file are you pointing to? Please show the exact configuration. By the way, the header [already wraps itself in `extern "C"`](https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/master/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/sha3.h#L35) if compiled as C++; so you don't need that.

Comment: I use `wolfssl.lib`. How I can share configuration to you?

Comment: I meant that you could add the link configuration to the question (either from the dialog or from the project file itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stephan,

I see you found the correct answer. For others reading this, the solution to this question regarding unresolved external symbol `wc_InitSha3_256` is to add the pre-processor flag `WOLFSSL_SHA3` to your settings. This can either be done in the Visual Studio Project settings under PreProcessor or you can update the settings in `wolfssl-root/IDE/WIN/user_settings.h` by adding `#define WOLFSSL_SHA3` and re-building the visual studio project. For other documentation on working with the wolfSSL windows solution please see the wolfSSL website under "docs" tab and look for document named "wolfSSL with Visual Studio" under the "Technical Documentation" section. Link provided below:

https://www.wolfssl.com/docs/visual-studio/

For any future questions pertaining to wolfSSL products if you add the flag "wolfssl" to your question we do have engineers that regularly check stack overflow for new questions and will be happy to post an answer! You can also contact us directly at support [at] wolfssl [dot] com anytime if your question goes unanswered. Simply send us a link to the stack overflow question(s) and we are more than happy to look into it!